# Why does Blender tell me this upon startup?

Tags: error

[image: invalid_token]

Does this have to do with BlenderKit assets? I just installed 2.81 and I’m working on a file I made in 2.8? I think it was saying this before that though. I’m not too familiar with the computer jargon side of things. What is a token and why is it refreshing?

It’s not preventing anything as far as I can tell but just want to understand/possibly remedy it.

Thanks!

John

Comment: Go to Window -> Toggle System console and give us a screenshot of that please, sometimes you get more information in there.

Comment: I think your guess is correct and this is coming from BlenderKit. The message is likely coming from `check_errors(rdata)` ([`search.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/blenderkit/search.py)) and `rerequest(method, url, **kwargs)` ([`rerequests.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/blenderkit/rerequests.py)). The messages are referring to your OAuth authentication token.